# wrong '.$row["column_name_here"].' encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I'm a bit newbi in PHP. I implemented http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/loading-more-results-from-database solution in my new website: http://do2go.pl/do2go-nowa/

its working well - except encoding. My DB and all things are in UTF8. When fetch taking data from DB UTF8 seems not working.

Heres configuration and fetch code:

Config:

```
<?php
$db_username = 'kamio2_do2gonowa';
$db_password = 'JeremiasZ1!';
$db_name = 'kamio2_do2gonowa';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$item_per_page = 2;
mysqli_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysqli_set_charset('utf8');


$connecDB = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name) or die('could not connect to database');


?>
```

And fetch:

```
<?php
include("config.inc.php"); //include config file
//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
    exit();
}

//get current starting point of records
$position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

//Limit our results within a specified range. 
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT id,introtext FROM w7wst_content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");

//output results from database

echo '<ul class="page_result">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'"><span class="page_message">'.$row["introtext"].'</span></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

?>
```

I added `mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysql_set_charset('utf8');` but this does nothing. Still getting � symbols and ? instead of " All next 3 was changed directly in DB tables for html symbols which isn't a solution.

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: This will fail `mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysql_set_charset('utf8');` don't mix MySQL APIs. Change to `mysqli_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysqli_set_charset('utf8');`

Comment: already did, thank you. But its still not working.

Comment: Can you try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside `<head></head>` and check to see if your file(s) is saved as UTF-8

Comment: it is - When u look at source u see meta charset already in source code. Whats strange I already added for example "ś" letter in fetch file right before '.$row["introtext"].' db content call out and it worked. It seems that issue is in the way of taking results from DB.

Comment: Try adding `$connecDB->set_charset("utf8");` just before `$results = mysqli_query($connecDB...`

Comment: So, any luck with what I suggested?

Comment: Great and you're welcome, I posted it as answer then to close the question. Just click on the checkmark till it turns Green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To close the question, since this was the solution to the OP's problem)

Add `$connecDB->set_charset("utf8");` just before `$results = mysqli_query($connecDB...`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if they are properly stored in the table? Try typing this in your database(not in PHP):

```
SELECT * FROM w7wst_content;
```

and see if it's displaying properly. Alternatively you can check table contents with some tool like phpmyadmin. If it's not you have to set collation to something like utf8_general_ci.

EDIT: Also, how about setting the charset AFTER connecting to the database, hm? :)

Comment: its for sure utf8_general_ci. This table is used for Joomla! 3 content component and its working well outside this script.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mysql and mysqli in one script. Only use mysqli as mysql has been deprecated. That said try this:

```
mysqli_character_set_name($connectDB);
mysqli_set_char_set($connectDB, 'UTF8');
```

Set these after your connection script.

Comment: changed for mysqli - no effect :(

Comment: Could you edit your post with any current code you have updated so we can see any changes made.

Comment: Remove the two char set scripts you have placed and replace them with the two I put above AFTER your connection script. Try that. Do not use the mysqli_query("SET Name") etc.